# Meaning of letters near Armor and Weapon in "Monster Hunter Freedom Unite"

Tags: monster-hunter-freedom-unite

I sometimes see letters in armor names and weapon names in Monster Hunter Freedom Unite:

- Buster Blade **G**
- Diablo **D** Armor
- Mafumofu **S** Armor
- Vespoid **U** Armor
- Blango **X** Armor
- White Fatalis **Z** Armor

I am guessing G is for "G-Rank", D is for "Dark", but I was wondering about the meaning of S, U, X and Z letters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G weapons are sets of weapons that similar to ones you get early in the game (e.g. the [Buster Blade](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Buster_Blade) and [Buster Blade G](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Buster_Blade_G)), but have G-ranked power/sharpness.

The letters S, U, X, and Z in armor names refer to them being [High](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/MHFU:_High_Rank_Blademaster_Armors) [Rank](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/MHFU:_High_Rank_Gunner_Armors) (S/U) and [G](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/MHFU:_G_Rank_Blademaster_Armors) [Rank](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/MHFU:_G_Rank_Gunner_Armors) (X/Z) variations of the [Low](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/MHFU:_Low_Rank_Blademaster_Armors) [Rank](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/MHFU:_Low_Rank_Gunner_Armors) (regular/D) armors, usually having vastly different, higher base defense, and/or better/more skills and slots than their previous iterations.